# Converting Difference between two DateTimes in to HH:MM:SS format in asp.net C# Databinding Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, data-access-layer

net application in which I needed to subtract two datetimes and display them in HH:MM:SS format. I'm fetching these from data base in mappling class and trying to subtract and convert to string format there. I'm trying in the following way

```
TimeTook = Convert.ToString(reader.GetDateTimeNullable("COMPLETED_DATE") - reader.GetDateTime("REQUEST_DATE"))
```

This statement is used in a mapping function and when I convert it into string i'm getting in days HH:MM:SS.ff format but i want to get it in HH:MM:SS format as i'm binding this directly to a label in an user control as follows

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblTimeTook" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TimeTook") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I want to bind directly the difference between two dates and display them in HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: If you subtract two `DateTime`s, you end up with a `TimeSpan`. Have you looked into that class' methods/properties? **edit** It's a struct, not a class :) Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: Look at String.Format and DateTime.ToString() methods (there are many here)

Comment: You subtract on your query and format it on sql.

Comment: I tried TimeTook=(reader.GetDateTime("COMPLETED_DATE") - reader.GetDateTime("REQUEST_DATE")).ToString("hhmmss") it is working properly but the time is displaying like 021314 whith out colons but when i use TimeTook=(reader.GetDateTime("COMPLETED_DATE") - reader.GetDateTime("REQUEST_DATE")).ToString("hh:mm:ss") it is throwing error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subtracting two `DateTime`s returns a `TimeSpan` which can be easily formatted:

```
TimeTook = ( reader.GetDateTimeNullable("COMPLETED_DATE") -
             reader.GetDateTime("REQUEST_DATE")
           ).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: It is throwing an error saying Input string was not in a correct format. I got this but when i changed ToString("HH:mm:ss") to ToString("hhmmss") this error was gone but the output displayed without colons

Comment: @user2864496 Sorry, forgot `TimeSpan` works a little different that `DateTime`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @D Stanley I want to know how to do the same thing with two nullable datetimes when i tried to use the above one it is throwing an error.

Comment: You can use `.Value` to get the actual `DateTime` value - you just need to decide what to do if one or both of them is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic (replacing the DateTime.Nows with your values:

```
        var datetimediff = new DateTime((DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) -    DateTime.Now).Ticks);
        var TimeTook = datetimediff.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetDateTimeNullable("COMPLETED_DATE") - reader.GetDateTime("REQUEST_DATE")).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: It is throwing following error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.